# not able to connect google drive to download torrent

Tags: github, backend, google-colaboratory, drive, torrent

when i press the connect button they are showing that no backend available and to try again later....when tried to login using another gmail there is no problem and it work like charm....can you please suggest any method how to byepass this....the site is https://colab.research.google.com/github/FKLC/Torrent-To-Google-Drive-Downloader/blob/master/Torrent_To_Google_Drive_Downloader.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

Colab does not support peer-to-peer file sharing, and using notebooks of this type seems likely to result in being prohibited from using the service.